# Difficulties changing header/column names using Pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

*EDIT: As user @Mayank Porwal pointed out I had forgotten to specify the keyword columns in df.rename command. I found another solution suggested by use @cs95 using str.rstrip to remove all suffix in the headers.*

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rstrip('_TEXT')
```

ORIGINAL QUESTION: I have data retrieved from an CSV file. The data is organized into columns with headers following a common naming scheme. I wish to remove the text (a suffix) automatically in each column without having to designate each old and new column name. None of the methods I have tried so far have worked.

Example using Pandas rename function

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df.rename({'B1A1 Average Length (um)':'B1A1'}, inplace=True)

df.head()
```

This returns

[image]

Any feedback and input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to specify the keyword `columns` in `df.rename` command. Try this instead:

```
df.rename(columns={'B1A1 Average Length (um)':'B1A1'}, inplace=True)
```

Basically, the command goes like this:

```
df.rename(columns={'oldName1': 'newName1', 'oldName2': 'newName2'}, inplace=True)

OR

df = df.rename(columns={'oldName1': 'newName1', 'oldName2': 'newName2'})
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Do you have any suggestions for how to loop this to all columns?

Comment: You can have 2 lists. One with current column names like (`df.columns`), other with new column names( you would have to make this manually I guess). Then using these lists, you can create a dictionary and pass it to the rename command.

Comment: Thanks again for the input. I found a solution using the command ---> df.columns = df.columns.str.rstrip('_TEXT'). :-)

Answer (score 1):

In this code pandas are looking for an index with the name 'B1A1 Average Length (um)', it will not work in your code since it is a column name.

- [WRONG] df.rename({'B1A1 Average Length (um)':'B1A1'}, inplace=True)
- [CORRECT] df.rename(**columns=**{'B1A1 Average Length (um)':'B1A1'}, inplace=True)

Answer (score 0):

If the suffix is consistent, you can use a list comprehension and the replace function to make the changes you need.

```
df.columns = [i.replace(" Average Length (um)","") for i in df.columns]
```

Comment: This result in an error message (SyntaxError: can't assign to function call)!

Comment: Okay, it should work now. I must have got turned around when actually typing up the answer, because you apply functions/methods to the first "i" in the list comprehension, not the second. What you see now is correct and it's something that I've used many times before.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [111]: df
Out[111]:
   obj  B1A1 Average Length (um)  B1A2 Average Length (um)
0    0                       2.0                       0.0
1    1                       0.0                       3.0

In [112]: df.rename(columns = { col : col.replace('Average Length (um)','').strip() for col in df.columns if 'Average Length (um)' in col } , inplace = True)

In [113]: df
Out[113]:
   obj  B1A1  B1A2
0    0   2.0   0.0
1    1   0.0   3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to removing suffix in header using str.rstrip

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rstrip('_TEXT')
```